# The L7805 got hot when connected to ATMega8?

Tags: voltage-regulator, linear-regulator

I tried to make the blinking LED example, I took the power from L7805 directly to ATMega8 and the output of MCU is through pin 28 to 3mm LED and 390 Ohm resistor.
But when I ran the project, the L7805 got hot quickly. What did I do wrong?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fultPJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is the input voltage at the input of 7805? Please post the circuit diagram.

Comment: No schematic, no voltage or current measurements, no picture. I'm going to make a wild guess and say you connected it up wrong.

Comment: add a scheme and show us, how you wired it

Comment: I inserted the schematic.

Comment: I wish if I can find someone to guide me through robotics way step by step.

Comment: You have a 12-5V = 7V drop across your regulator. At 100mA that will be 7V*0.1A=0.7W depending on the package this will make your part hot. I'd also check to make sure you have your AtMega8 hooked up right.

Comment: When supplied with 12v a 7805 may well need a heat sink.  Also you have not connected all of the required power and ground pins on the ATmega; you must connect them all, not just some of them.

Comment: Get a DMM and make some intelligent measurements

Comment: What frequency you are running your ATMega at? What package is the 7805 regulator? TO-92?

Comment: @Ayman - (a) Please edit your question & add close-up, in-focus photos of your actual hardware, for us to confirm the connections to MCU pins & component part numbers. Wiring or MCU orientation mistakes could mean that reality does not match the schematic. (b) Does the MCU also get hot with power on, as well as the 7805? (c) Your schematic (if correct) is not strictly a valid minimum ATmega8 circuit (although it may *partially* work) - also connect pin 22 to Gnd, and connect pin 20 to VCC. Any change? (d) How are you programming your MCU? Your schematic shows no programming connections.

Comment: you think that's hot? try putting an ESP32 on there to make a portable knuckle roaster.

Comment: i tried now to connect the LED to PB0 Instead PC5. and the circuit worked correctly with no heat. when it was on PC5 the led didn't blink and the regulator got hot. why was all that ?

Answer (score 1):

there is about 7 volts difference between the input and the output of the voltage regulator. At least a 2-4 volts difference is recommended and also both the micro-controller and the led draw current enough current to heat up the regulator provided the voltage drop. Linear Voltage regulator are not so efficient.

you can try any of these to deal with the heat

1.try placing a 100 ohm resistor(1 watt) in series between the +12 volt terminal and input of the voltage regulator to limit some current to the voltage regulator. This may heat up the resistor though but its okay. You can completely ignore heat sink since the regulator will barely get warm.

2. try reducing the input voltage to 9 volts. This will reduce the voltage difference between the input and output of the voltage regulator. power dissipation will drop leading to less heating of the regulator.
3. or you can use a DC-DC buck converter which is much more efficient than linear voltage regulator. Like this
   [https://www.amazon.com/MakerHawk-Converter-Efficiency-Regulator-Adjustable/dp/B07F3S5ZDX/ref=sr_1_17?crid=11HDKBHVFZAOQ&keywords=buck+converter&qid=1563946855&s=gateway&sprefix=buck+conver%2Caps%2C394&sr=8-17](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F3S5ZDX)

Answer (score 0):

The LM7805 is a linear voltage regulator that works essentially like a variable resistor to reduce the voltage. The excess energy from the reduction of the voltage is converted to heat so as you can imagine, the higher the input voltage the more heat produced even with the load current constant.

In your scenario the load current is given by (assume the output of a digital I/O pin to be 5V): 
$$\ \ Load \ Current =  \frac{V_{pin28}}{ R_1}  $$
$$\ \ Load \ Current =  \frac{5V}{390 \Omega} = 12mA$$

Ignoring no load current and the MCU current, the power dissipated by the 7805 is given by :

$$\ Power= \Delta V\times I =(V_{IN}-V_{OUT})\times Load\ Current$$

$$\ Power= (12-5)V\times 12mA = 0.084W$$

This is ignoring some other current demands so it might be a bit more so I imagine you would feel the heat on the 7805 IC, assuming you've wired up everything correctly. All in all use a heatsink if you're worried, the IC has internal thermal overload protection so you will know if your circuit is drawing more power than what the 7805 can handle.

Unrelated to the question however you're not using the recommended capacitor values on the inputs and outputs. This isn't what's causing your heating but it's to handle noise in the supply :

[image: 7805 Typical Application Schematic]

Comment: 7 V x 12 mA does not equal 0.84 watts.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast misread the calculator there, thanks

Comment: "not using the recommended capacitor values on the inputs and outputs. This isn't what's causing your heating"

Not so sure about that. Lacking caps can cause the regulator to oscillate which in turns heats it up. Happened to me trying to drive an ESP8266 (Wemos D1). Almost burned my fingers. I added the caps and the heat went away.

Comment: thanks for these information, it is too helpful to me. i tried now to connect the LED to PB0 Instead PC5. and the circuit worked correctly with no heat. when it was on PC5 the led didn't blink and the regulator got hot. why was all that ?

Comment: 0.084 watts shouldn't heat the the regulator.